# Android Native with Jetpack Compose Kotlin and Java Dependency Problems

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

All I wanted to do in my Android Native app using Jetpack Compose was to use some of the newer versions of some of the software. I guess I should have known better, because this has turned into the usual dependency nightmare. I have wasted all afternoon trying to get this to compile and run.

I’ll start with the error message, and work backwards:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> e: This version (1.2.0-alpha05) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.7.10 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
```

First, I have no idea why the `compileDebugKotlin` thinks I am targeting JVM 1.8 instead of 17. My `JAVA_HOME` is set to Java 17, my IntelliJ Project Structure JDK is set to 17, and my `app:build.gradle` has the following:

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

I do not see `1.8` being set anywhere.

The next issue is the Compose Compiler version that the error message is showing, `1.2.0-alpha05`. I am setting the following in my root `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    compose_version = '1.3.0'
…
```

And then referring to it in my `app:build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
```

I have no idea where it’s coming up with `1.2.0-alpha05` as the version.

The next issue is that it thinks I'm using Kotlin `1.7.10`. I have set the Kotlin version to `1.6.10` in the IntelliJ preferences for Kotlin compiler, as well as `17` for the JVM. I tried the following in `build.gradle`, but it seems to be ignored, it is making no difference:

```
kotlin {
  version("1.6.10")
}
```

In a nutshell, I have no idea where any of these version numbers are coming from, and how to set them so that they reflect the reality that I thought I was configuring correctly. I have cleared the IntelliJ cache and restarted numerous times.

Comment: ```android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.2"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}```
check this values
and can you share your both build.gradle file using pastebin.com or smtng and share link here

Comment: Thanks, @Dilshad, the `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` and `jvmTarget` were the keys to my problem. All is good now!

Comment: @Dilshad feel free to post your answer so that Dave can get you the proper credit. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the two task shown in the error have different functions during a build
`compileDebugJavaWithJavac` is responsible for generating the bytecode for the Java Code and making it available for further processing. which in your case is targeted to java 17 but `compileDebugKotlin` is responsible for making bytecode for kotlin code in your case it is targeted to `1.8` ,that is not supported so you should add

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

2. composeCompiler is not Compatible with all versions of Kotlin. Each compose compiler has corresponding compatible Kotlin Version ([Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#pre-release_kotlin_compatibility)). what you shown is `compose_version` which do not represent Compose Compiler, they are declared in

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.x.x"
    }
```